# Capturing Self in a double block with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, self

I recently learned this trick for when I have to reference self within a block.

```
__weak MyObject *safeSelf = self;  
[self doWithCompletionBlock:^{

    HMFInventoryBatchItemsController *strongSelf = safeSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf doSomethingElse];
    }
}];
```

But I've been wondering, what if I have a block within a block? Do I need to do the same thing again?

```
__weak MyObject *safeSelf = self;  
    [self doWithCompletionBlock:^{

        HMFInventoryBatchItemsController *strongSelf = safeSelf;
        if (strongSelf) {

            __weak MyObject *saferSelf = strongSelf;  
            [strongSelf doAnotherThingWithCompletionBlock:^{

                HMFInventoryBatchItemsController *strongerSelf = saferSelf;
                if (strongerSelf) {
                    [strongerSelf doSomethingElse];
                }
            }];
        }
   }];
```

Or is this fine

```
__weak MyObject *safeSelf = self;  
    [self doWithCompletionBlock:^{

        HMFInventoryBatchItemsController *strongSelf = safeSelf;
        if (strongSelf) {

            [strongSelf doAnotherThingWithCompletionBlock:^{

                    [strongSelf doSomethingElse];

            }];
        }
   }];
```

Comment: Why reassigning self with HMFInventoryBatchItemsController *strongSelf = safeSelf; Since self is ownership of the block?

Comment: You don't have to make a strong reference in block unless you want to access its ivar.

Comment: I found this article as a reference http://amattn.com/2011/12/07/arc_best_practices.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good answer is, it depends. It's in general unsafe to do:

```
__weak MyObject *safeSelf = self;

[self doWithCompletionBlock:^{
      [safeSelf doAnotherThingWithCompletionBlock:^{
              [safeSelf doSomethingElse];
       }];
}];
```

The reason for that, is that when you call `-doAnotherThingWithCompletionBlock` if that method *thinks* it holds a reference on `self`, which a selector usually assumes, and it dereferences self to access ivars, then you will crash, because you actually don't hold a reference.

So whether you need to take a new weak reference or not depends on the lifetime semantics you need/want.

**EDIT:**

By the way, clang even has a warning about that issue that you can enable in Xcode with the `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_RECEIVER_WEAK` setting (`CLANG_WARN_OBJC_REPEATED_USE_OF_WEAK` is also useful while we're at it)

Comment: You probably mean "method" instead of "selector". And you probably also mean "referencing ivars" instead of "dereferencing ivars", means `self->someIvar;` ;)

Comment: indeed, I just reworded my answer

Comment: It's not unsafe since self own the block object. In this case self will never be a dangling pointer from the block object stack. If you don't do that, self will never be freed, same for the block. The only case where it could happen, is when you forget to freed a owned asynchrony block, and that's not good anyway . With ARC now, this never happen. By the way "__block" should be used instead of "__weak" semantic.

Answer (score 0):

```
__block MyObject *safeSelf = self;

    [self doWithCompletionBlock:^{
          [safeSelf doAnotherThingWithCompletionBlock:^{
                  [safeSelf doSomethingElse];
           }];
   }];
```

Hope it will do what it should normally does. Tell the compiler not to retain the __weak MyObject* no matter in which block scope it is. The fact is i didn't tested. Meanwhile I'll be surprised if it will actually retain MyObject *

Comment: Is there any way to test this?

Comment: You can use retaincount and watch if safeself has a +1 count inside the block (of course make a simple code who can guaranty that "self" is not retained elsewhere.). The second way is when you release the object after using the block call (assuming your blocks are ivars and not local to the function scope). If dealloc is never called, then your blocks has retained the block ownership object. The purpose of "__weak" is actually to prevent that.